# display page in page viewer webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can add a link to a page in SharePoint without showing the ads in this page! I don't have any control on that page.

Is there any option to show page in page viewer web part without ads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you already don't have any control for this page, So how you can hide or show something on a page without having control!

Meanwhile, in `the page viewer web part`, you don't have any settings to disable obtrusive ads event for a page you have control!!

you can only set the page URL to show it as **IFrame** regardless what's the content of this page and what it will show?

but generally, if you need to block obtrusive ads during browsing internet, you can use extensions in google browser called [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en-US)